# Let Ω=[0,1], B(Ω) the Borel Sigma algebra and Leb the Lebesgue measure on Ω.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let's say that X Is a random variable defined under (Ω,B(Ω),Leb) And 
Y: Ω->R Is given by: 
Y(w)=w(1-w)1Ω(w)
Determinate E(X|Y)(w)for each w that belongs to Ω.

I've been going through some probability problems and I got stuck in this one, I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Could you give us some context?  What have you tried and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: At first I thought $1\Omega$ was just $1_\Omega$ written without the benefit of MathJax. But that would trivialize the question. So what is that notation (in the definition of $Y$) intended to mean?